# Calculus Complicated Substitution Derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

When,

$$y=6u^3+2u^2+5u-2 \ , \ u= \frac{1}{w^3+2} \ , \ w=\sin x -1 $$find what the derivative of $ \ y \ $equals when $ \ x = \pi \ . $

Tried it many times, still can't seem to get the right answer (81)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{du}\cdot\frac{du}{dw}\cdot\frac{dw}{dx}$$
$\frac{dy}{du}=18u^2+4u+5$, $\frac{du}{dw}=\frac{-3w^2}{(w^3+2)^2}$ , $\frac{dw}{dx}=\cos x$

Can you now make the substitutions?

Note that when $x=\pi $, then $w=-1$, and $u=1$

Comment: Numerical problems like this are nice because you don't have to worry about tidying up the expression to get $ \ y' \ $ written as a function of $ \ x \ $ alone.

Comment: Would you mind expanding on where and what to substitute?

Comment: I give you the values of $x,w,u$ to substitute them in $dw/dx,du/dw,dy/du$. The only thing you have to do is substitute and then multiply the partial derivatives.